# Removing duplicate values based on two columns

Tags: awk, columns, duplicate

I have a file that would like to filter duplicate values based column 1 and 6

```
ID,sample,NAME,reference,app_name,appession_id,workflow,execution_status,status,date_created
1,ABC,XYZ,DOP,2022-08-18 13:31:09Z,28997974,same,Complete,PASS,18/08/2022
1,ABC,XYZ,DOP,2022-08-18 13:31:09Z,28997974,same,Complete,PASS,18/08/2022
1,ABC,XYZ,DOP,2022-08-18 13:31:09Z,28997974,same,Complete,PASS,18/08/2022
1,ABC,XYZ,DOP,2022-08-18 13:31:09Z,28997974,same,Complete,PASS,18/08/2022
2,ABC,XYZ,DOP,2022-08-18 13:31:09Z,28997974,same,Complete,PASS,18/08/2022
2,ABC,XYZ,DOP,2022-08-18 13:31:09Z,28997974,same,Complete,PASS,18/08/2022
2,ABC,XYZ,DOP,2022-08-18 13:31:09Z,28997974,same,Complete,PASS,18/08/2022
2,ABC,XYZ,DOP,2022-08-18 13:31:09Z,28997974,same,Complete,PASS,18/08/2022
```

and the final output should look like

```
ID,sample,NAME,reference,app_name,appession_id,workflow,execution_status,status,date_created
1,ABC,XYZ,DOP,2022-08-18 13:31:09Z,28997974,same,Complete,PASS,18/08/2022
2,ABC,XYZ,DOP,2022-08-18 13:31:09Z,28997974,same,Complete,PASS,18/08/2022
```

So far this is what I have tried

```
awk '!a[$1 $6]++ { print ;}' input.csv > output.csv
```

I end up with

```
ID,sample,NAME,reference,app_name,appession_id,workflow,execution_status,status,date_created
1,ABC,XYZ,DOP,2022-08-18 13:31:09Z,28997974,same,Complete,PASS,18/08/2022
2,ABC,XYZ,DOP,2022-08-18 13:31:09Z,28997974,same,Complete,PASS,18/08/2022
2,ABC,XYZ,DOP,2022-08-18 13:31:09Z,28997974,same,Complete,PASS,18/08/2022
```

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: if you do use `!a[$1, $6]++` (which is better you do it) instead of the `!a[$1 $6]++`, are you geting the same wrong output? what is the field delimiter of your input file? what is your file type `file input.csv`?

Comment: I can't get the same failure as you with your code and data, although that command may be shortened to `awk '!a[$1,$6]++' file`.

Comment: its a csv file, that's strange, I still get 3 records with awk '!a[$1,$6]++' file

Comment: @nbn It's not a CSV file, there does not seem to be a fix field delimiter. `awk` will use any sequence of spaces and/or tabs as the delimiter. If one of your fields contain spaces or tabs, it will be treated as more than one field by `awk`. You have no such data in your example in the text as far as I can see, unless `ABC XYZ DOP` or `2022-08-18 13:31:09Z` is supposed to be a single field.

Comment: `2022-08-18 13:31:09Z` is one field but `ABC XYZ DOP` are all three different columns